# Cant see half of line in tkinter python

Tags: python, windows, graphics, tkinter

I am creating a game and I want to add some graphics. I tried to create a line, but I can see only half of it.

[image: Screenshot showing a line that only goes about halfway across the window]

And this is my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
import calculate

class Core(tk.Tk):

def run(self):
    self.mainloop()

def show_frame(self, page_name):
    '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
    frame.tkraise()

def __init__(self, color):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self)

    container = tk.Frame(self)
    self.geometry("600x600")
    self.configure(background=color)

    self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)


    self.iconbitmap('icon.ico')

    self.frames = {}
    for F in (Home, Game):
        page_name = F.__name__
        frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[page_name] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")


class Home(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)


class Game(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        canvas.pack(side='top', fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        canvas.create_line(0, 0, 600, 600)
        #calculate.drawp(100, canvas, 600, 120, 300, 600, self)



def main(color):
    app = Core(color)
    app.show_frame("Game")
    app.run()

main("#e67e22")
```

I don't see a reason why this is happening. Could you help me?

Comment: you have wrong indentions - edit question and use button `{}` to pass code with correct indentions.

Comment: Canvas doesn't use full window.

Comment: Your canvas is not taking all the window

Answer (score 1):

Canvas doesn't use full window so you don't see full line.

Use

```
container['bg'] = 'red'
```

and you will see

[image]

You can resize Canvas

```
canvas.config(width=600, height=600)
```

Or you can set minimal size of cell in grid

```
container.columnconfigure(0, minsize=600)
container.rowconfigure(0, minsize=600)
```